# how to active a link using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following links

```
   <ul class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
        <li><a href="#" class="dir" onClick="clickMe('Wall'); selectedTab('Wall');">Wall</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dir" onClick="clickMe('Introduction');">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dir" onClick="clickMe('Activities');">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dir" onClick="clickMe('Reviews');">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dir" onClick="clickMe('Recommendation');">Recommendation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dir" onClick="clickMe('Photos');">Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="dir" onClick="clickMe('Discussion');">Discussion</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and if I click on any link then it must be high lighted.

Comment: It's javascript without any space in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm:

```
<a href="#" id='photos'
onclick="var photos=document.getElementById('photos');photos.style.background='chartreuse';false;">
Photos</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the [a:active](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pseudo_active.asp) CSS psuedo-selector.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need javascript to do this. Some CSS rules are enough.

Depending on which behaviour you need you could use one or all of this HTML pseudo-selectors (**:link**, **:visited**, **:hover**, **:active**).

The link selector specifies the behavior of the link when It's not clicked nor activated for any reason, in other words in its normal state.

The **:active** pseudo-class adds a style to an element that is activated.

If you need to be more specific and for example want to highlight what you **mouseover** (in other word only when the link is under your mouse) put this in the head section of your HTML:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    a:hover { background: #fbdbe8; color: #F55B99;}
</style>
```

If you want to highlight what you already **visited** vs what not put this in the head section of your HTML:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    a:visited { background: #fbdbe8; color: #F55B99;}
</style>
```

Then every clicked link would be highlighted when you come back to the page.

You can, of course add the style rules I said in an external .css file instead of having them in the head.

Comment: Whenever you want to define them all in the style, remember the **LoVe HAte** ordering: `a:link`, `a:visited`, `a:hover`, `a:active`. Else it may go mad in some browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use jquery

You would have somthing like:

```
$('.menuItem').click(function() {
    $('.current').removeClass("curret"); // To remove the highlight from the previous selection
    $(this).addClass("current") 
});
```

Then in your css you would declare current with the styles you want. One advantage of this vs the css pseudo selector is that you can do something like $(this).parent() to access the parent element of the link, in case your menu is a ul.